# Getting MATLAB variable (string) from C

Tags: c, matlab, matlab-engine

I'm writing a small C application that launchs a Matlab script (.m file).
I need to exchange some variables and I don't know how to get an array of chars that exists in Matlab.

I'm doing something like this:

```
enter code here
result = engGetVariable(ep,"X");
if (!result)
    {
    printf ("Error...");
            exit -1;
    }

int n = mxGetN(result);

    char *varx = NULL;
    memcpy(varx, mxGetData(result),n*sizeof(char));
```

It doesn't work. Does someone know how to get a Matlab string in C?
I've read Matlab documentation about engGetVariable() and the provided example but any of this things clarify me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to memcpy into memory that you never allocated.
char *varx = malloc (sizeof(char) *bytes_you_need); before you do that. Setting char * to NULL means it has no memory address, and thus cannot serve as a reference to any memory.... set it to the return value of malloc, where malloc has set aside some bytes for your data.

```
char *varx = malloc (sizeof(char) * n);
memcpy(varx, mxGetData(result),n*sizeof(char));
printf ("%s\n", varx);
free(varx);
```

Comment: Ok, this is a problem (let me say a "lack of coffee" ;-))
But, declaring varx like you said or "char varx[1000]" there are still problems. 
I have been debugging and I found that if I have a variable in Matlab like "X='Hello folks!' when retriving it in C I have this:
varx[0]='H' varx[1]='\0' varx[2]='e' varx[3]='\0'.. and so on.

Maybe it's because in Matlab characters have 16 bits... and I'm working with 8bits. 
Doing in Matlab "X=int8('Hello folks!') seems to work but fails with some characters.

Thanks!!

Comment: yep, you nailed it. it's giving you back utf8, since you're getting ascii the first 8 bits will be the same, so skipping every other char will work. you might also try using wchar_t and doing it the wide character way, but it might not be necessary for your purposes. (wchar_t == char * 2)

Comment: I'm doing the conversion in Matlab (that it's easyer :-) to uint8 and works like a charm!